# Python: update attribute value if not None

Tags: python, null, sqlalchemy, attributes

I want to update the values of columns in my SQLAlchemy DB if the attribute does not equal None.

This method works but it doesn't seem to follow the DRY principal

```
def editObject(object_id, name, picture, metaTitle, 
    metaKeywords, metaDescription):

    object = session.query(Object).filter_by(id = object_id).one()

    if name:
        object.name = name
    if picture:
        object.picture = picture
    if metaTitle:
        object.metaTitle = metaTitle
    if metaKeywords:
        object.metaKeywords = metaKeywords
    if metaDescription:
        object.metaDescription = metaDescription

    session.add(object)
    session.commit()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use keyword arguments and [setattr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
def editObject(object_id, **kwargs):

    object = session.query(Object).filter_by(id = object_id).one()

    for attr, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        if value:
            setattr(object, attr, value)

    session.add(object)
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using keyword arguments, `setattr`, and a list comprehension:

```
def editObject(object_id, **kwargs):

    object = session.query(Object).filter_by(id = object_id).one()

    [setattr(object, key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items()]

    session.add(object)
    session.commit()
```

Then when you call the function, for example:

```
object_id = 1
attributes_to_update = {"name": "smith", "metaKeywords": "handsome_devil"}
editObject(object_id, **attributes_to_update)
```

In that example only `name` and `metaKeywords` would be updated.